# Jsoup is not loading full HTML page, it loads only partial

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to learn Jsoup with an example, i am trying to load a website URL in Async Task. But it is loading only partial instead of full HTML page. I want to remove some of the component like header, footer etc and let it display on WebView. Not sure what might be missing:

I have tried with multiple options:

Options 1:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jsoup.org/discussion")
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .get();
```

Options 2:

```
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jsoup.org/discussion").maxBodySize(0).timeout(50000).get();


class PageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jsoup.org/discussion").maxBodySize(0).timeout(50000).get();
            Logging.InfoLog(doc.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Many web pages load and render additional content through asynchronous JavaScript calls *after* the page is loaded. JSoup only returns the initial HTML of the page.

If you need to process pages that load and render content dynamically, you need a different set of tools, like htmlunit, but htmlunit will only work in your backend code.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Volgin for your quick reply. I will check with HtmlUnit tool also. I am trying to get some of the part from the dynamic, static web page. Sometime i would like to remove header, footer etc. I want to show the page on Android WebView only specifc part (i.e. not fully as it is). Hoping i should be able to do it by HtmlUnit. Any other good tool or suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Abhrajyoti Kirtania Load the webview in the background, invoke javascript after the site completed loading (including javascript content) to remove/change content, then display the webview. In my experience HtmlUnit is slow and often still not able to handle the scripts. Depending on the content sometimes you can also use a combination of jsoup and rhino to get what you want.

Comment: @F.Klein, I am wondering how to load complete HTML, i had tried with JSoup but it is not loading full HTML page which is the main problem. Could you please suggest what would be the best way to load the HTML page. I hope once loading is success, JSoup can be used to parse the page to have full control of the page for any kind of modification and customisation. Are you suggesting to loading raw html data via WebView and then convert it to Document via JSoup? Or any other thought please?

Comment: JSoup is loading half of the HTML page, how to load complete HTML page? I am thinking about loading of raw HTML and convert it to Documents via JSoup

Comment: @AbhrajyotiKirtania everything you can do with jsoup you can also do with JavaScript. I really like jsoup and use it quite often, but loading a site in a WebView, grab the rendered html source, modify it with jsoup, load the modified source into the WebView and probably repeat for every on page navigation sounds impracticable. Have a look at the basic example for WebView usage with JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/153/using-webview#t=201610031706345338765 (meant to write a more extensive guide for JavaScript and CSS injection, might be able to do so this week).

Comment: @F.Klein: I agree. If you already have access to a proper browser with JavaScript engine, there is no need to pull in another headless browser with JS engine just to remove the header and show it in the web view.

Comment: @FredericKlein, I able to remove the header and footer with java script putting in "onPageFinished" of webView client but i could see initially it is loading and displaying the complete page and after fraction of sec it is removing and showing custom page onto the view. Is there any way to load only the custom view instead of showing initially full page.

Comment: @AbhrajyotiKirtania you could create a new webview, load the page, alter the page, assign it to the view. I would display a spinner or progress bar though, to give the user some feedback, while the page is loading.

Comment: @FredericKlein, thanks for reply. But i am struggling to extract HTML source from web view as "public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)" gives Web view after java script run. Is there any way to get html source from WebView which can be loaded on WebView?

Answer (score 0):

I found that **the problem isn't Jsoup**.  **The problem is Android Studio**.

Jsoup loads the full HTML page without any problems.  But if you try to print a long HTML page in Android Studio console using Log.i() or some other Log method, then this page will get cut off at some point.

Apparently, Android Studio limits the amount text you can print in its console.

So, my suggestion is to show the received HTML in a `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`.  In Kotlin, the code would look as follows:

```
fun getWebPage(){
    Thread(Runnable {
        var doc = ""
        try {
            val url = "https://jsoup.org/discussion"
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
                                             rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .get().toString()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.message)
        }

        activity!!.runOnUiThread(Runnable { textView.text = doc })

    }).start()
}
```

And the xml for displaying it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".JsopFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Result ..."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</ScrollView>
```

I've tested this code, and it shows the whole page.